# Capacitor voltage function

Tags: voltage, capacitor, discharge

How would you find the mathematical function of the voltage discharge curve for a capacitor considering the following circuit and conditions:

- When time t=0, the capacitor is fully charged with the voltage V.
- The current through resistor R is not negligible.
- The constant current source is "powerful" enough to bring down the voltage of that node.

[image]

If the exact function cannot be determined, maybe at least some individual points could be found.

I tried to apply Kirchhoff's law:

[image: I_R (t)+I_C (t)=I_cst]

which means:

[image]

and after integrating

[image]

[image]

At this point I don't know what to do since I cannot integrate an unknown function: Uc(t) (which is also the function I want to find).

Any ideas or different approaches?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you get to this point:

[image]

you have to solve a first order differential equation:

https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/differential-equations-first-order-linear.html

Comment: Thank you! from the link you provided I was able to solve the differential equation which turned out as: 

RC*((Icst*R-V)+Constant) 

Unfortunately, after I plotted this function into a graph drawer and swapped the R, C, Icst, V and varied the constant I only got a straight horizontal line. I'll have to check everything again.

Comment: It should have an exponential in it... here is [WolframAlpha's answer]( https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+u%3A+%28V%2Du%28t%29%29%2FR+%2B+C%2Au%27%28t%29+%3D+I)

Comment: Finally got the link in my previous comment correct!

Comment: Ohh, it makes a lot of sense. Turned out that I messed up an integration. Now it is very clear. Thank you so much for the help and for the fast responses!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the \$V\$, \$R\$ combination with its Norton equivalent: a current source \$V/R\$ in parallel with \$R\$. Combine the two current sources (add) then convert back to the Thevenin equivalent: voltage source \$(V/R-I_{cst})R\$ in series with \$R\$. Then, instead of connecting the current source at \$t=0\$, solve for a capacitor charged to \$V\$ discharging through \$R\$ to \$(V/R-I_{cst})R\$ starting at \$t=0\$. This is a familiar exponential with time constant \$RC\$.

After you're introduced to the concept of a time constant, probably in second semester college physics, you'll know that the answer will have an exponential. \$V_C\$ starts at \$V\$ and ends at \$V - I_{cst}R\$, so you write
$$
V_C(t) = V - I_{cst}R(1-e^{-t/RC}).
$$
Done.

Comment: nice approach, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the later edit also. Eventually I figured out that I should see how the capacitor charging trough a resistor formula is determined, and used the the same principle to find the formula for my particular case. Thanks again for your input!